# How do I protect people walking around my deck from banging their head on this overhanging platform?

Tags: deck, safety

Below is the picture showing the platform that I am talking about

[image]

The plan is to have the barbeque under that so that aspect is taken care of. Probably a plant toward the house end of that underneath area. My question is more about adding some foam or something on the wood joist that holds the platform but I still need to preserve the modern look of my deck

Comment: Make the BBQ slightly bigger than the overhang, so people can't walk into the wood joist. Asking about what to put on the joist itself, while preserving the modern look, is off-topic as it's a shopping or design question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put small eyebolts on the bottom edge of the platform.  Hang things off of it -- plants, bird feeder, vertical sign panels, etc.

Could be art of some kind.  Could be just a square of plywood painted gray, that's a *kind* of art.  (The kind I know how to paint.)

Or it could be exactly what it says on the tin: actual warning signs with some twist made to be humorous.  Maybe battling warning signs, each calling the other unsafe!

So many possibilities.  At the end of the day, what will people who are enjoying your yard want to look at?

Comment: Hanging some plants might work, Wraping some planters around that ...the planter will be plastic and very flexible

Answer (score 1):

Put something underneath it, or cordon it off somehow. This prevents them from walking close enough to hit their head in the first place.

You can plant some shrubs or flowers underneath it; make sure to get appropriate sun / shade tolerant plants. You could put a little sculpture, or just landscape it with mulch. People tend to avoid walking on mulch, even if there's nothing planted.

The other option is to put some kind of barrier around it. A small fence, some large rocks / boulders, etc.

Edited after your edit: Make the BBQ slightly bigger than the overhang, or stick out further than the overhang. Supplement with plants or other ideas from my answer if needed. This prevents people from being able to walk where they would hit their head in the first place, negating the need for any foam or other material on the overhang itself.